# psql db dump on digital ocean server to local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, hosting, digital-ocean

I have an app running on Ubuntu on digital ocean, and I want to do a db dump to my local machine. It's a rails app.

I've tried running the following, but get tcp/ip error:

```
ssh name@555.555.55.555 -C pg_dump  -U username | psql -U username
```

How can I do a db dump from Ubuntu to my local machine?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to server via ssh, execute command and save to local machine:

```
ssh user@machine "pg_dump -U user_name -h host -p port db_name" /
>> backup_file_on_your_local_machine.sql
```

Better way - try to connect with `pg_dump` to remote host:

```
pg_dump -U user_name -h host -p port db_name > dump_file
```

**port** usually is `5432`,
**host** - localhost

Comment: Thanks @idej, I get the following message when i run that command: "pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "/" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: @AnthonyPinto sorry, I didn't specify all arguments of pg_dump. Edited

Answer (score 0):

If you have pg installed on your system, you could do this:

```
pg_dump -U user_name -h remote_host -p /
remote_port name_of_database > name_of_backup_file
```

More information on [this Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-backup-postgresql-databases-on-an-ubuntu-vps).

I hope this helps!